# Finding optimal values from multiple parameter estimation runs

Tags: optimization, reference-request, error-estimation, probability, genetic-algorithms

I've performed a parameter estimation repeat (i.e. 1000 parallel runs with the same
initial values of parameters). I am trying to estimate ~20 parameters using measurements from experiments.

After running the estimation task (using Evolution strategy algorithm) for 10 hours (using --maxTime argument), the results were obtained.

When I look at the distribution of the objective values, the values fall in the range  (900, 2000).  There are several combinations of parameter values that I obtain for objective values that lie in the same order of magnitude. I understand increasing the duration of the estimation run may decrease the objective value further, but I think I would still end up with several sets of parameter values.

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to process these results.
If there are some references that I could read to understand how to cluster these results and find an optimal parameter set, that would be of great help.

Comment: Are you trying to quantify the uncertainty in the fitted parameters due to randomness in the measured data?   If so, this isn't the way to do that.

Comment: Which of the 1,000 parallel runs resulted in a solution that best fit the data overall?

Comment: @BrianBorchers The lowest objective value was ~900.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Let's assume the 100th run yields an objective value of 900 and `set1` is the set containing the optimal values/results of the 100th run.  I was trying to see whether the solution of other runs e.g. 200th run will yield a result `set2` = `set1` plus minus `delta` such that delta is small (since I cannot expect a unique solution ).  But from my results, I could see the  the difference or delta is large. i.e if I plot a distribution, the values are not centered around a peak value

Comment: It may be that many of your runs are simply failing to find a "good" solution.